# Shopify liquid how to output account creation date

Tags: html, object, shopify, liquid

When members login to their account I would like to output the account creation date. So if an account was created on May 14, 2018 it would say "May 14, 2018". I have tried a few different variations of the code below, however nothing has worked.

```html
{{ customer.account.created_at | date: "%b %d, %y" }}
```

Comment: `customer.created_at` is not returned in Liquid. Here is the [list](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/customer) of attributes that are available to the liquid code

Comment: The closest you would have would be to look at the customer's orders and use the date of the earliest order (if one exists). Not ideal and not quite what you're looking for, but if all else fails `customer.orders` is a thing

Comment: You could also tag customers with something that indicates their account-creation date.